# Postfix Relay Access Denied When Sending To Gmail With Telnet

Tags: email, imap, smtp, telnet, postfix

I have postfix and dovecot setup to deal with mail for my domain. imap appears to work ok when reading local mail but when i try to send an email using telnet with localhost and the smtp port it gives me the relay access denied error.

```
    [root@vps69576 ~]# telnet localhost smtp
    Trying ::1...
    Connected to localhost.
    Escape character is '^]'.
    220 mail.domain.net ESMTP Postfix
    ehlo domain.net
    250-mail.domain.net
    250-PIPELINING
    250-SIZE 10240000
    250-VRFY
    250-ETRN
    250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
    250-AUTH=PLAIN LOGIN
    250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
    250-8BITMIME
    250 DSN
    mail to:
    501 5.5.4 Syntax: MAIL FROM:<address>
    mail from:dan@domain.net
    250 2.1.0 Ok
    rcpt user@gmail.com
    554 5.7.1 <user@gmail.com>: Relay access denied
```

The contents of the main.cf file are

```
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix

command_directory = /usr/sbin

daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix

data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
mail_owner = postfix

myhostname = mail.domain.net

mydomain = domain.net

myorigin = $mydomain

inet_interfaces = all

inet_protocols = all

mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain

unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, <site IP>

relay_domains = 

alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases

alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases

home_mailbox = Maildir/

sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix

newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix

mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix

setgid_group = postdrop

html_directory = no

manpage_directory = /usr/share/man

sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/samples

readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.6.6/README_FILES

smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_sasl_authenticated,permit_mynetworks, reject_unauth_destination
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_sasl_path = private/auth
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are connecting to localhost via IPv6 (::1), but that address is not part of the "mynetworks" list. Change it to

mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8, <site IP>, [::1]/128

and it should work.

Comment: This partially worked. "telnet localhost smtp" executes fine and the mail was delivered. when i use telnet smtp.domain.com 25 it gives me another relay error. It is using the ipv6 of my domain which ends with ::3e0. im assuming its because the /128 doesnt cover the range from this hex number. I tried pasting the ipv6 ip into mynetworks and it causes an error when i run telnet

Comment: i got around this by copying the ipv6 address with square brackets around it so [xxxx:xxxx:xxx::xxx]

Comment: Right – it depends what IP address you are connecting from.

To be sure, you can put all local IP addresses into mynetworks, like this:

    mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128 [2001:db8:1407:c3a0::]/60 128.66.85.168